# Dynamically replace method implementation on an object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'd like to replace the implementation of a method for an object with a block that the user specifies. In JavaScript, this is easily accomplished:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = function(x) { console.log(x) }
}
foo = new Foo()
foo.bar("baz")
foo.bar = function(x) { console.error(x) }
foo.bar("baz")
```

In C# it is also quite easy

```
class Foo
{
    public Action<string> Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

var foo = Foo.new();
foo.Bar("baz");
foo.Bar = x => Console.Error.WriteLine(x);
foo.Bar("baz");
```

But how can I do the same in Ruby? I have a solution that stores a lambda in an instance variable and the method calls the lambda, but I don't really like the overhead and syntax

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @bar = lambda {|x| puts x}
  end

  def bar x
    @bar.call x
  end

  def bar= blk
    @bar = blk
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar "baz"
foo.bar= lambda {|x| puts "*" + x.to_s}
foo.bar "baz"
```

I'd like to have a syntax like that:

```
foo.bar do |x|
    puts "*" + x.to_s
end
foo.bar "baz"
```

I came up with the following code

```
class Foo
  def bar x = nil, &blk
    if (block_given?)
      @bar = blk
    elsif (@bar.nil?)
      puts x
    else
      @bar.call x
    end
  end
end
```

But this is kinda ugly for more than one parameter and still doesn't feel 'right'. I could also define a set_bar method, but i don't like that either :).

```
class Foo
  def bar x
    if (@bar.nil?)
      puts x
    else
      @bar.call x
    end
  end

  def set_bar &blk
    @bar = blk
  end
end
```

So question is: Is there a better way do to do this and if not, what way would you prefer

Edit:
@welldan97's approach works, but i loose the local variable scope, i.e.

```
prefix = "*"
def foo.bar x
    puts prefix + x.to_s
end
```

doesn't work. I suppose I have to stick with lambda for that to work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use `def`:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar "baz"

def foo.bar x
  puts "*" + x.to_s
end

foo.bar "baz"
```

yes, that simple

Edit: To not loose the scope you can use `define_singleton_method`(as in @freemanoid answer):

```
 prefix = "*"

 foo.define_singleton_method(:bar) do |x|
   puts prefix + x.to_s
 end

 foo.bar 'baz'
```

Comment: oh well, that was probably too easy \*facepalm\* :)

Comment: hmm, I loose the scope to local variables, i.e. `prefix="*"; def foo.bar x; puts prefix +  x.to_s; end` doesnt work :/

Comment: @welldan97, how can I replace method "setter" for specific object?

Comment: @gaussblurinc, if you want to redefine one of setter methods it's pretty much the same `foo = {}; foo.define_singleton_method(:bar=) { |x| self[:bar] = x }; foo.bar = 5; foo # => { bar: 5 }`, if I understand correctly what you want

Comment: @welldan97, yes you understand me. But I can't understand you now :) you create an structure, not an object. I mean I want to redefine method "setter" for specific object, not structure

Answer (score 4):

You can implement what you want like this:

```
class Foo; end

foo = Foo.new
prefix = '*'
foo.send(:define_singleton_method, :bar, proc { |x| puts prefix + x.to_s })
foo.bar('baz')
"*baz" <<<<<-- output
```

This is absolutely normal and correct in ruby.