# What is the use in class/static methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, methods

Learning ruby and oop in general, I came upon class methods which as far as I understand are like instance methods but are accessed from the class rather than from an object and can have only one running at the same time.

However, I don't understand why you would use a class method versuses a normal method (outside a class) and what is even their use?

For example:

```
#Why would you use:
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "Class method"
  end
end

#Versus simply:
def bar
  puts "Normal method"
end

Foo.bar # => Class method
bar # => Normal method
```

As they both produce the same result?
I'm quite confused about them so please correct if I'm misunderstanding any/everything here.

Comment: You should read some basic OOP book. That will help more to understand this basic concepts.

Comment: @maximus Could you recommend any (or free online ones even better!)?

Comment: To learn basic OOP concept, I suggest you to read o'reilly series book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596008673.do and to learn the same with ruby. Book of ruby is best http://www.sapphiresteel.com/ruby-programming/The-Book-Of-Ruby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example isn't a good one.

Class methods might deal with managing all instances that exist of a class, and instance methods deal with a single instance at a time.

```
class Book
  def self.all_by_author(author)
    # made up database call
    database.find_all(:books, where: { author: author }).map do |book_data|
      new book_data # Same as: Book.new(book_data)
    end
  end

  def title
    @title
  end
end


books = Book.all_by_author('Jules Vern')
books[0].title #=> 'Journey to the Center of the Earth'
```

In this example we have a class named `Book`.  It has a class method `all_by_author`.  It queries some pretend database and returns an array of `Book` instances.  The instance method `title` fetches the title of a single `Book` instance.

So the class method managing a collection of instances, and the instance method manages just that instance.

---

In general, if a method would operate on a group of instances, or is code related to that class but does not directly read or update a single instance, then it probably should be a class method.

Answer (score 4):

This is more an OOP question than a ruby one. Class methods in ruby are used the same as in other OO programming languages. This means:

- class methods are run in the context of a class (and have access only to class variables)
- instance methods are run in the context of an object (and have access to object's or instance variables)

Here is a better example:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def baz
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

Foo.bar # => "class method"
Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class

Foo.new.baz # => instance method
Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar
```

Here you can see that class method is accessed through a class, while instance method is accessed through an instance or object of a class (`Foo.new`).

Example is copied from [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/), where you can also find more information on this subject.

Keep in mind: although any code can be put into a class or a instance method, each has it's own use cases and own pros and contras. In OOP we strive for reusable, flexible and readable code, which means that we usually want to put most of the code as structured as instance methods in a sensible domain model.

Answer (score 3):

Just as you said, they are:

- "accessed from the class rather than from an object and"
- "can have only one running at the same time."

remember, too, that the class is portable

Comment: So is it more of an organisational thing rather than different functionality

Comment: That is between a normal method and a class method

Comment: @user2521439 yes, just organizational

Comment: @user2521439 there is no "normal method" - you are just calling a method within the klass that is your current scope.  Prove it to yourself by calling `self.class` in your 'normal' scope

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that it keeps your code organized. When you have hundreds of thousands of lines of code, having them all haphazardly throwing stuff around in the same namespace can become a nightmare. Organization is really important, and namespaces are an easy way to get modularity with support from the language.

Somewhat less importantly, class/module methods can share state without leaking it all over the place (e.g. classes can have instance variables), and they can have private support methods to allow for better factoring, while global methods can't effectively be made private.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of misunderstanding,

In ruby, we can define class and instance method.

Class method is used to do provide processing at class level i.e. data which can only be available at class level or related to all the objects. For example, to count the number of objects belongs to class you need class method. Like

```
Foo.count
```

In same way, to process single object you need object method to process a single object like,

```
obj.save
```

So, class method is example of singletone design pattern where object can have there own implementation of same method.

Comment: in ruby you can add/modify method in object dynamically. As in obj.define_singleton_method(:new_method) do
  "do some things"
end

Comment: Modifying existing method from object can be done by simple assignment like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786495/dynamically-replace-method-implementation-on-an-object-in-ruby